# Visual Studio: Handling Typescript and LESS project files (with TFS Build)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, less, typescript, tfsbuild

I currently have an ASP.Net MVC project setup that uses `.less` files and standard `.js` files.

My `less` files get compiled when they're saved by the Web Essentials Visual Studio extension, and appear like so:

[image: LESS Files]

One annoying thing I have to do is set the `less` file's Build Action to '`None`' so it doesn't end up in the built files on the server, but that's manageable.

I've added the TypeScript extension to Visual Studio, and I'm starting to convert my `.js` files over to `.ts` files.  Similar to the `.less` files, they will be recompiled when I save the `.ts` file; however, the `.js` file is not added to my project.  This is an issue since TFS won't have the `.js` file for its build (and won't compile the file, since that TypeScript tool doesn't exist there).

I can add the `.js` file to the project, and then hack the project file to make it a dependency:

[image: Typescript]

However, this process also seems like a bit of a pain.  So to my question:  What is the correct approach I should be taking here?

1)  Do not include `.css` and `.js` files in TFS, and find a way to have our TFS server compile these during build (add the `.ts` extension somehow, and is there a build action for compiling `.less`?).

2)  Include all files like I'm currently doing, but find a better way of adding `.ts` files (without editing the project file) and `.less` files (without needing to change the build action).

So far I haven't been able to find a good solution for either route.

Comment: So when you save the `.ts`, and it generates the `.js`, it doesn't want to add it to source control? Can you right click on the generated `.js` and say "Add to Solution?"

Comment: Sidenote: check out the [NestIn extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d6ef0ce-2bef-4a82-9a84-7718caa5bb45). It's useful for grouping similar files easily. I nest page-specific styles and scripts right under the page and have a build script that compiles and minifies everything. It's great.

Comment: Dleh, yep, and that's what I'm currently doing.  @DavidSherret, that looks great!  I think I'd prefer having the build server compile these files, but I think that extension with my current process will do for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go with option 1. Only commit the Less and Typescript  files and let the build system generate the css and Javascript.

Comment: I'm all for doing this, but I have yet to find a good way of going about it (especially for typescript).  I tried following the recommendation from this article: http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/09/typescript-on-your-build-server.html , however, by the time I had all of the references working, the build server would just say "tsc.exe exited with code 1" with no further explanation

Answer (score 1):

Since asking this question, we've upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and left TFS for Atlassian, but this should still be applicable:

I deleted all generated css files and added the following gulpfile.js to the project:

```
/// <binding AfterBuild='less' ProjectOpened='less-watch' />
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var path = require('path');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var lessPaths = [*my file paths*];
gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src(lessPaths, { base: "./" })
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(concat('app-styles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles/'));
});
gulp.task('less-watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(lessPaths, ['less']);
});
```

This concats all of my generated files into a '/styles/app-styles.css' file.  From there, we need to add the following to the .csproj file to get this new file copied into our output folder on build/deploy:

```
<Target Name="GulpTasks" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="node_modules\.bin\gulp less" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="styles\app-styles.css" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\styles" />
  </Target>
```